# Is there a more efficient and elegant way to filter pandas index by date?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I often use DatetimeIndex.date, especially in groupby methods. However, DatetimeIndex.date is slow when compared to DatetimeIndex.year/month/day. From what I understand, it is because the .date attribute works with a lambda function over the index and returns a datetime ordered index, while index.year/month/day just returns integer indices. I have made a small example function that performs a bit better and would speed up some of my code (at least for finding the values in a groupby), but I feel that there must be a better way:

```
In [217]: index = pd.date_range('2011-01-01', periods=100000, freq='h')

In [218]: data = np.random.rand(len(index))

In [219]: df = pd.DataFrame({'data':data},index)

In [220]: def func(df):
 ...:     groupby = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month, df.index.day]).mean()
 ...:     index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], periods = len(groupby), freq='D')
 ...:     groupby.index = index
 ...:     return groupby
 ...: 

In [221]: df.groupby(df.index.date).mean().equals(func(df))
Out[221]: True

In [222]: df.groupby(df.index.date).mean().index.equals(func(df).index)
Out[222]: True

In [223]: %timeit df.groupby(df.index.date).mean()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.32 s per loop

In [224]: %timeit func(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 89.2 ms per loop
```

Does the pandas/index have a similar functionality that I am not finding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even improve it a little bit:

```
In [69]: %timeit func(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 84.3 ms per loop

In [70]: %timeit df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1D')).mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 6 ms per loop

In [84]: %timeit df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='1D')).mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.48 ms per loop

In [71]: (func(df) == df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1D')).mean()).all()
Out[71]:
data    True
dtype: bool
```

another solution - using [DataFrame.resample()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) method:

```
In [73]: (df.resample('1D').mean() == func(df)).all()
Out[73]:
data    True
dtype: bool

In [74]: %timeit df.resample('1D').mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.63 ms per loop
```

**UPDATE:** grouping by the string:

```
In [75]: %timeit df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y%m%d')).mean()
1 loop, best of 3: 2.6 s per loop

In [76]: %timeit df.groupby(df.index.date).mean()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.07 s per loop
```

Comment: `df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y%m%d')).mean()`?

Comment: @MaxU Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VolkrB, glad i could help :)